# Properties of timelike congruences in flat spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames

I'd like to learn about (or confirm) certain properties of [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)), concerning some presumably rather simple cases, namely of timelike congruences in the setting of flat spacetimes $\mathcal S$. Therefore I have here three closely related questions:

**1.**
Are there at least two (or more) distinct timelike congruences, each covering a given ***1+1*** dimensional flat spacetime region, which are not disjoint (but which have at least one curve in common) ?

**2.**
Are there at least two (or more) distinct timelike ***geodesic*** congruences, each covering a given ***1+1*** dimensional flat spacetime region, which are not disjoint (but which have at least one curve in common) ?

**3.**
Are there at least two (or more) distinct timelike ***geodesic*** congruences, each covering a given ***2+1*** dimensional flat spacetime region, which are not disjoint (but which have at least one curve in common) ?

Proofs or examples should be given preferrably in terms of the spacetime intervals $s^2 : \mathcal S \times \mathcal S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ whose values may be presumed given for flat spacetime region $\mathcal S$ under consideration.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. Consider a 1+1 spacetime with metric $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$. In congruence A, the curves are $(t,x)=(t,x_0)$, with one curve for each value of $x_0$. In congruence B, the curves are $(t,x)=(t,x_0+v|t|)$ with $v=x_0/(1+|x_0|)$. If a smooth congruence is desired, we can smooth out the kinks at $t=0$ without changing the basic idea. The two congruences share the same $x_0=0$ curve.
2. No. In flat spacetime in the usual coordinate system, geodesics are straight lines. In a plane, the straight lines in a congruence must all be parallel so they don't intersect.
3. Yes. Consider a $2+1$-dimensional spacetime with metric $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2-dy^2$. In congruence A, the geodesics are $(t,x,y)=(t,x_0,y_0)$, with one geodesic for each value of $x_0$ and $y_0$. In congruence B, the geodesics are $(t,x,y)=(t,x_0+vt,y_0)$ with $v=y_0/(1+|y_0|)$. The two congruences share the same $y_0=0$ geodesics.